# Finding combinations not permutations of pairs using Prolog

Tags: prolog

Im trying to figure out how to get Prolog to generate all possible pairs from a deck of cards. I have found example where lists are used to represent all possible cards in the deck, and then using the list to get possible pairs. However I would like to generate pairs directly from the relations of card instead of using a list of cards. The problem im having with a naive implementation is that im getting all permutations instead of combinations, that is get:

C1 = king spade 
C2 = king club
AND
C1 = king club
C2 = king spade

But in my example these two pairs are the same.

Below is how I represent cards in Prolog.

```
suite(spade).
suite(heart).
suite(diamond).
suite(club).

num(queen).
num(king).
```

Now my questions are:
1. What is the reason most examples uses lists when deling with different card combinatorial examples instead of using relations directly to query for possible pairs, straights etc?
2. How would a predicate look to query for all possible pairs combinations given the relations shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is definitely *not* the case: Quite a few examples use the facts directly and build pairs from them without using lists at all. However, a list is a natural representation for a hand of cards, so it is no wonder that somewhere along the way lists *will* make an occurrence.
2. For a canonical representation, consider imposing an order on the cards. Take for example the Prolog standard order of terms and write:

```
:- op(400, xfx, of).

suite(spade).
suite(heart).
suite(diamond).
suite(club).

num(queen).
num(king).

pair(A-B) :-
        num(NA),
        suite(SA),
        num(NB),
        suite(SB),
        A = (NA of SA),
        B = (NB of SB),
        A @< B.
```

Example query:

```
?- pair(P).
P = queen of heart-queen of spade ;
P = queen of diamond-queen of spade ;
P = queen of diamond-queen of heart ;
P = queen of club-queen of spade ;
P = queen of club-queen of heart ;
P = queen of club-queen of diamond ;
P = king of spade-queen of spade ;
P = king of spade-queen of heart ;
P = king of spade-queen of diamond ;
P = king of spade-queen of club ;
P = king of heart-queen of spade ;
P = king of heart-queen of heart ;
P = king of heart-queen of diamond ;
P = king of heart-queen of club ;
P = king of heart-king of spade ;
P = king of diamond-queen of spade ;
P = king of diamond-queen of heart ;
P = king of diamond-queen of diamond ;
P = king of diamond-queen of club ;
P = king of diamond-king of spade ;
P = king of diamond-king of heart ;
P = king of club-queen of spade ;
P = king of club-queen of heart ;
P = king of club-queen of diamond ;
P = king of club-queen of club ;
P = king of club-king of spade ;
P = king of club-king of heart ;
P = king of club-king of diamond ;
false.
```

As you see, the pair `king of club-king of spade` does occur, but `king of spade-king of club` does not. Such a canonical representation will make many checks a lot easier for you.